# undefine reference to function

Tags: arrays, function, reference, undefined, structure

Hi this is my first time posting here, and I am relatively new to coding so I am having a lot of problems with it. Most of the time I can learn it on my own on on how to fix error, but now I think I just hit a major road block with arrays and structures. At the moment, when compiling it will give me

```
undefined reference to `buildArrays(std::string, int, int, int)'
```

The problem is, I keep having this error every time I try to "fix" the buildArray caller in the main function, changing the string PlaName to a char PlaName [25] in the stucture Players somehow works but doesn't change the error . Is there anyway I can try to change the code so that the array will be probably call from a function into another function? Most of the info I have looked up for this error mostly talks about linkers, Which doesn't help.

Btw my homework requires me to create an array from a file, call it from a function, in the main function and to use that array throughout the rest the main function. I don't know if the program works, since I can't get pass the undefined reference error. Here most of the program:

```
using namespace std;

struct Players
{
    string PlaName;
    int PlaGoal;
    int PlaAssist;
    int Points;
};

int buildArrays( string, int, int, int);
void printArrays( string, int, int, int, int);
void sortArrays( string, int, int, int, int);

int main()
{
Players player;

   buildArrays(player.PlaName,player.PlaGoal,player.PlaAssist,player.Points); //this is the error

  cout<<"Chicago Blackhawks UNSORTED Report;";


}

int buildArrays( string playerNames[], int goals[], int assists[], int rating[] ) //this function's format is required for the homework
{
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("hockey.txt");
    if (inFile.fail())
        {
        cout<<"The hockey.txt input file did not open";
        exit(-1);
        }

    while (inFile)
        for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
        {
        inFile >> playerNames[i]
               >> goals[i]
               >> assists[i]
               >> rating[i];
        cout<<playerNames[i]<<goals[i]<<assists[i]<<rating[i];
        }
        inFile.close();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your buildArrays function prototype does not match your function definition. Your function takes in arrays, but your prototype does not use the array syntax. 
Change your prototype to look like this:

```
buildArrays( string[], int[], int[], int[] ) ;
```

Also your main() function needs to pass in arrays into the buildArrays() function. Creating a single struct and passing each member will not be sufficient. Perhaps you need to rework how you organize your data if you have to use the buildArrays() function format for your homework. Perhaps create separate arrays for each piece of player data and then create an array of structs after calling buildArrays().

Comment: Yes it works now, it seems that the structure was the main problem. Maybe there was no possible way to keep the arguments in the buildArray and data in Players coherent for the compiler. Thanks for the help.